# The user is not able to access the list which has unique permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-permissions, unique-permissions

The user is not able to access a list which has unique permission than the parent, In that case what should be done?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the list permissions and add the user to the list manually, or add the user to a group that already has access to the list.

Comment: Added manually, but still no access

Comment: What permissions does the user have for the list? What permissions does the user have for the parent site? How does the user try to get to the list?

Comment: The users has edit their own item but no delete permission for the list, the users have Read access to the Parent site. There is a button on the homepage from where they can go to the list.

Comment: When you go to the list settings > list permissions and check for the user permissions, what permissions does the user have for the list? Editing your own items is not a permisision, that's an advanced setting.

Comment: Yes, when i check for user permission, it shows that he/she has "edit only no delete" permisson for that list.

Comment: What EXACT message does the user get when they go to the default view of the list, e.g. `https://myclient.sharepoint.com/sites/theSite/lists/thelist `?? Use a URL like this without a named view. The URL must end in the list name.

Comment: You are right, the URL of the button has "view name" after the list name in the URL. How do i change the URL for the button?

Comment: That is not what I was after. I don't need you to change the button. I just want to know what the user sees when they use the URL to the list without using a particular view. That is a troubleshooting step, not a fix. So, what message does the user get?

Comment: You don't have access, Request Access

Comment: What do you see in the List Settings > Permissions for this list > Check Permissions (in the ribbon) > enter the user name > Check now button

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message when the user access to the list?

Remove user's permission on the list and re-grant permission for the user, compare the results.

If the issue still exists, try to grant user with contribute or full control permission on the list, compare the results.